# Javascript replace() function adding strange characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, fancybox, character

Consider the following Javascript:

```
var previewImg = 'http://example.com/preview_img/hey.jpg';
var fullImg = previewImg.replace('preview','full');
```

I would expect the value of `fullImg` to be:

```
http://example.com/full_img/hey.jpg
```

In fact, it is... sort of. Running `alert(fullImg);` shows the expected url string. But when I deliver that variable to jQuery [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/), like this:

```
jQuery.fancybox.open(fullImg);
```

Something adds characters into the string, like this:

```
http://example.com/%EF%BF%BCfull_img/hey.jpg
```

Where is this `%EF%BF%BC` coming from? What is it? And most importantly, how do I get rid of it?

Some other clues: This is a Drupal 7 site, running jQuery 1.5.1. I'm using that same Fancybox script elsewhere on the site with no issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%EF%BF%BC` is a sequence of three URL-encoded characters.

You clearly can't see any unexpected characters in the string. That's because the character sequence `%EF%BF%BC` is invisible.

It's actually a UTF-8 byte-order mark sequence. This sequence typically comes at the start of a UTF-8 encoded text file. They probably got into your code when you did a copy+paste from another file.

The quickest way to get rid of them is to find the bit of code that was copied+pasted, delete the characters on either side of the problem, and retype them. Depending on your editor, you may find the delete behaves strangely as it deletes the hidden characters.

Some text editors and IDEs will have an option to show hidden characters. If your editor has this, it may help you see where the mystery characters are so you can delete them.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1. `IDEs will have an option to show hidden characters` @sam : additionally you could set the encoding to ANSI so it will be easier to spot them, then revert the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM after deleting those unwanted characters.

Comment: Genius! Interestingly, my IDE (Coda 2) has a "Show Invisible Characters" option (which I use often for situations such as this) but nothing showed up when I toggled it on. Only when I set the encoding to "Western (ASCII)" did the strange characters appear! Deleted! Now it's running fine. The only remain question is where did they come from? I'm pretty sure I hand typed the whole script...